# React native getting updated state for save

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm quite new to react native and i didn't found any solution to my problem yet so I'm asking here now. I'm trying to update the state of a value on an `onPress` event of a radio button and save it afterwards. The problem is that the save is getting the non updated value. I know `setState` is an async call and a `forceUpdate` is not a recommended solution(and don't work for me for some reason)

here is a sample:

```
import RadioForm, { 
  RadioButton, 
  RadioButtonInput, 
  RadioButtonLabel
} from 'react-native-simple-radio-button'

class SomeClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      buttonValues: [{label: "someValue1", value: 0}, {label: "someValue2", value: 1}],
      someString: "someStringValue_false"
    }

    this.handleOnPress = this.handleOnPress.bind(this),
    this.saveValue = this.saveValue.bind(this)
  }

  handleOnPress(value) {
    if( value === 1 ){
      this.setState({
        someString: "someStringValue_true"
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        someString: "someStringValue_false"
      })
    }
  }

   saveValue() {
    //no problem in this function tested already in other cases
   }

  render() {
    return( 
      <View>
        <RadioForm
          radio_props={this.state.buttonValues}
          initial={0}
          formHorizontal={true}
          labelHorizontal={true}
          radioStyle={{paddingRight: 20}}
          buttonColor={"red"}
          selectedButtonColor = {"green"}
          animation={true}
          onPress={(value) => this.handleOnPress(value)}
        />
        <Button
          title={"save"}
          onPress={()=> this.saveValue()}
        />
      </View> 
    )
  }
}
```

Behavior: the state updates only on the 2nd call

Comment: Did you console.log the variable "value" in handleOnPress method ?

Comment: yeah on someValue2 in prints out 1 and on someValue1 it prints 0 so the behavior is as expected and goes like expected in the if right if block

Comment: where are you putting the `console.log`?. Move that log inside `componentDidUpdate` and check if works as expected.

Comment: my console.log is inside the 'handleOnPress' method in both if and else blocks and i dont have a 'componentDidUpdate'

Comment: Are you meaning to set two different state values in `handleOnPress`, shouldn’t they both be `someString`?

Comment: yes sorry my bad i didnt see that both values should be someString

Answer (score 2):

you can try yo use `setState` callback

```
setState({ name: "Michael" }, () => console.log(this.state));

// => { name: "Michael" }
```

to make sure that the state changes.

Comment: yes it returns the correct expected state on the callback

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding the handlers with `this` properly in the constructor. It should be

```
constructor(props) {

/* --- code --- */

this.handleOnPress = this.handleOnPress.bind(this),
this.saveValue = this.saveValue.bind(this)
```

}

Comment: yeah just realised but in my real code thats not the case i added them here by accident

Answer (score 0):

Do the next.

```
this.setState({
 meter_reading_unit: "someStringValue_false"
}, () => {
 console.log('meter_reading_unit ==> ', this.state.meter_reading_unit); // should be `someStringValue_false`
});
```

inside your next render update the value `someStringValue_false` should be available inside anywhere.

Comment: sorry i totally messed up i forgott to change the meter reading_unit to someString so yeah sorry for that my bad

Comment: and yes if i call that as a callback it gets the updated state